# How do I implement ListView animations with Viewpager?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, swipe-gesture

I'm a noob to android development and I am having trouble trying to implement the [ListView animations library](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) .  I have no problems implementing this library's functionality on regulars views.  However, it seems the swipe gestures intended for the listview items are being intercepted by the viewpager, which causes the library to be useless. I have tried using the NonswipableViewPager class to no avail. I've seen this this library used within a viewpager before so i know it can be done.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

CODE:

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            int resId = 0;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                    ...

                    locations_listview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                    locations_listview.setOnItemClickListener(Child_Locations_Activity.this);
                    setContextualUndoAdapter();

                    ...
 }


private void setContextualUndoAdapter() {
        ContextualUndoAdapter adapter = new ContextualUndoAdapter(location_adapter = new Child_Locations_ListAdapeter(Child_Locations_Activity.this, location_data), R.layout.layout_undo_row, R.id.undo_row_undobutton);
        adapter.setAbsListView(locations_listview);
        locations_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setDeleteItemCallback(Child_Locations_Activity.this);
    }
```

Comment: From a UX standpoint horizontal swipe gestures on a ListView within a horizontal pager are a nightmare. When should the swipe be a paging action and when should it be a list item deletion? You're going to have confused users if you do this. Better to follow the selection guidelines (http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html) and use a contextual action bar.

Comment: Hmm.  I never even considered a contextual action bar.  Thank you for the guidance.